# The whole App stops after an error of prop undefined (need help to debug)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, debugging

Reproduction of bug:

**1.** There is list of advertiser (our clients) for which we execute some marketing campaigns.

**2.** When you click on "Campaign" button of some advertiser.

**Result:** You are redirected on the "campaigns" page and there are all 
   campaigns of choosed advertiser.

**3.** But after clicked "Campaign" button for redirecting you on campaigns, some times **not always**, get the error prop "name" is
undefined.
Screenshot:
[image]

Here is the main logic which is executed after clicked on "Campaign" button.
**header.component.ts:**

```
    @Input() advertiserId: string;
    @Input() advertiserIoId: string;
    @Input() campaignId: string;

    public advertiserDto: AdvertiserDto;

    // This prop have value which is undefined in the moment of rendering: "AdvertiserIoDto"
    public advertiserIoDto: AdvertiserIoDto;
    public campaignDto: CampaignDto;

    constructor(private advertiserModel: AdvertiserModel,
                private advertiserIoModel: AdvertiserIoModel,
                private campaignModel: CampaignModel) {
    }

     ngOnChanges() {
        this.getAdvertiserDto();
        this.getAdvertiserDtoData();
        this.getAdvertiserIoDto();

        // here is the problem getAdvertiserIoDtoData()
        this.getAdvertiserIoDtoData();
        this.getCampaignDto();
        this.getCampaignDtoData();
    }

    private getAdvertiserDto(): void {
        this.advertiserDto = this.advertiserModel.getDto(this.advertiserId);
    }

    private getAdvertiserIoDto(): void {
        this.advertiserIoDto = this.advertiserIoModel.getDto(this.advertiserIoId, this.advertiserId);
    }

    private getCampaignDto(): void {
        this.campaignDto = this.campaignModel.getDto(this.campaignId, this.advertiserId, this.advertiserIoId);
    }

    private getAdvertiserDtoData(): void {
        this.advertiserModel
            .getDtoData(this.advertiserDto)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    private getAdvertiserIoDtoData(): void {
        this.advertiserIoModel
            .getDtoData(this.advertiserIoDto)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    private getCampaignDtoData(): void {
        this.campaignModel
            .getDtoData(this.campaignDto)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

header-template - part ({{ advertiserIoDto.dtoData.name }}) - here is undrefined dtoData.name:

```
<span *ngIf="campaignDto.isLoaded === true"
      [routerLink]="['/private/advertiser/' + advertiserId + '/advertiserIo/' + advertiserIoId]"
      class="nano-breadcrumb-item">
    {{ advertiserIoDto.dtoData.name }}
</span>
```

**One more important thing** if you compare order of execution in the "ngOnChanges" and "Browser",
 you will see that "getAdvertiserDtoData()" is started before "getCampaignDtoData()" but executed later. 
I think that is problem.

Screenshot:
[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Error Trace:

```
NanoCampaignHeaderComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (NanoCampaignHeaderComponent.html:16)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13105)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12557)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12252)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12531)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12257)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12599)
```

Comment: Please post the trace of your error as text.

Comment: And your error is about `something.name`, but I can't find a `name` in your code. Consider posting the code in error, not some random code.

Comment: error is about advertiserIoDto.dtoData.name. This advertiserIoDto is object which have "dtoData" property.  And dtoData have name property.

Comment: You should have precised that in your orgininal post. Use the safe navigation operator (or Elvis) and you're good to go : `{' advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?.name || 'Default text here (can be empty string)' }}`

Comment: dtoData is just model of all property which get from api - advertiserIo.

Comment: @trichetriche you mean to change the on html string interpulation on this way:
 {{ advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?.name || '' }}

Comment: Yes. You can also use `'---'` as a default value, that was what I was trying to say : empty quotes are usually not needed, since Angular has nothing to display, it will display nothing.

Comment: @trichetriche I tested now and you solve my problem. Thank you very much.
Can you please explain to me what happen here now:
{{ advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?.name || '' }}
Cus I din't understand, what now I made this two property option:? advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?  and if they are empty print | ' '     empty string?

Comment: Let me make an answer

Comment: @trichetriche thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments : in Javascript, you can write conditions in a way that they return values.

For instance :

```
let obj = { a: true, b: true };
console.log(obj.a && obj.b);
```

What do you think will pop ? Probably `true` :

```js
let obj = { a: true, b: true };
console.log(obj.a && obj.b);
```

Well in fact, it doesn't display *the result of the boolean* : it displays **the last value of the condition**. This is very well pictured with strings :

```
let obj = { a: 'A', b: 'B' };
console.log(obj.a && obj.b);
```

Now, you might say it should display `true` again (because of [*truthy and falsy*](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) values). But check that :

```js
let obj = { a: 'A', b: 'B' };
console.log(obj.a && obj.b);
```

`B` is displayed. As said, **the last value of the condition** is returned.

Why am I explaining that to you ? Simply because when you write this

```
advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?.name
```

This is actually a shortcut for this

```
advertiserIoDto && advertiserIoDto.dtoData && advertiserIoDto.dtoData.name
```

Which means, if you understood, that `advertiserIoDto.dtoData.name` will be returned at the end.

And then, you have an OR statement :

```
{{ advertiserIoDto?.dtoData?.name || '' }}
```

this is again related to this behavior : when all of the values are falsy, the OR statement is returned. Let me show you an example :

```js
let obj = { a: '', b: '' };
console.log(obj.a && obj.b || 'No value');
```

Since `''` is falsy, neither condition is fullfilled : the code returned is the OR statement.

This is the very same principle in Angular : you just have the safe navigation `?` in HTML as a shortcut.